# Capybara and JavaScript: checking for visibility requires huge amounts of time! How to optimise?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, capybara

While creating some JavaScript functionality in Rails, I use some ugly Capybara specs to help me assuring everything works. One of these specs looks like this:

```
it 'creates a report document', js: true do
  visit new_project_report_document_path @project

  expect(page).to have_active_navigation_items 'Projects'
  expect(page).to have_breadcrumbs 'A4AA 2.0', 'Projects', 'Project test name', 'Reports', 'Create'
  expect(page).to have_headline 'Create Report'

  expect {
    select 'Template 1', from: 'report_report_template_id'
  }.to change { page.has_css? "[data-template-inputs-id='#{@report_template_1.id}']", visible: true }.from(false)
  .and change { page.has_css? "[data-template-inputs-id='#{@report_template_1.id}'] #report_name[disabled]",        visible: false}.from(true)
  .and change { page.has_css? "[data-template-inputs-id='#{@report_template_1.id}'] #report_description[disabled]", visible: false}.from(true)
  .and change { page.has_css? "[data-template-inputs-id='#{@report_template_1.id}'] #report_intro[disabled]",       visible: false}.from(true)
  .and change { page.has_css? "[data-template-inputs-id='#{@report_template_1.id}'] #report_content[disabled]",     visible: false}.from(true)
  .and change { page.has_css? "[data-template-inputs-id='#{@report_template_1.id}'] #report_outro[disabled]",       visible: false}.from(true)

  expect(page).to have_css "[data-template-inputs-id='#{@report_template_1.id}'] #report_name",        text: @report_template_1.name
  expect(page).to have_css "[data-template-inputs-id='#{@report_template_1.id}'] #report_description", text: ''
  expect(page).to have_css "[data-template-inputs-id='#{@report_template_1.id}'] #report_intro",       text: @report_template_1.intro
  expect(page).to have_css "[data-template-inputs-id='#{@report_template_1.id}'] #report_content",     text: @report_template_1.content
  expect(page).to have_css "[data-template-inputs-id='#{@report_template_1.id}'] #report_outro",       text: @report_template_1.outro

  expect {
    select 'Template 2', from: 'report_report_template_id'
  }.to change { page.has_css? "[data-template-inputs-id='#{@report_template_1.id}']", visible: true }.from(true)
  .and change { page.has_css? "[data-template-inputs-id='#{@report_template_1.id}'] #report_name[disabled]",        visible: false}.from(false)
  .and change { page.has_css? "[data-template-inputs-id='#{@report_template_1.id}'] #report_description[disabled]", visible: false}.from(false)
  .and change { page.has_css? "[data-template-inputs-id='#{@report_template_1.id}'] #report_intro[disabled]",       visible: false}.from(false)
  .and change { page.has_css? "[data-template-inputs-id='#{@report_template_1.id}'] #report_content[disabled]",     visible: false}.from(false)
  .and change { page.has_css? "[data-template-inputs-id='#{@report_template_1.id}'] #report_outro[disabled]",       visible: false}.from(false)
  .and change { page.has_css? "[data-template-inputs-id='#{@report_template_2.id}']", visible: true }.from(false)
  .and change { page.has_css? "[data-template-inputs-id='#{@report_template_2.id}'] #report_name[disabled]",        visible: false}.from(true)
  .and change { page.has_css? "[data-template-inputs-id='#{@report_template_2.id}'] #report_description[disabled]", visible: false}.from(true)
  .and change { page.has_css? "[data-template-inputs-id='#{@report_template_2.id}'] #report_intro[disabled]",       visible: false}.from(true)
  .and change { page.has_css? "[data-template-inputs-id='#{@report_template_2.id}'] #report_content[disabled]",     visible: false}.from(true)
  .and change { page.has_css? "[data-template-inputs-id='#{@report_template_2.id}'] #report_outro[disabled]",       visible: false}.from(true)

  expect(page).to have_css "[data-template-inputs-id='#{@report_template_2.id}'] #report_name",        text: @report_template_2.name
  expect(page).to have_css "[data-template-inputs-id='#{@report_template_2.id}'] #report_description", text: ''
  expect(page).to have_css "[data-template-inputs-id='#{@report_template_2.id}'] #report_intro",       text: @report_template_2.intro
  expect(page).to have_css "[data-template-inputs-id='#{@report_template_2.id}'] #report_content",     text: @report_template_2.content
  expect(page).to have_css "[data-template-inputs-id='#{@report_template_2.id}'] #report_outro",       text: @report_template_2.outro

  fill_in 'report_name',        with: 'newname'
  fill_in 'report_description', with: 'newdescription'
  fill_in 'report_intro',       with: 'newintro'
  fill_in 'report_content',     with: 'newcontent'
  fill_in 'report_outro',       with: 'newoutro'

  click_button 'Create Report'

  expect(page).to have_flash 'Report was successfully created.'
end
```

I know that it's an ugly spec, but what I noticed is that it takes a huge amount of time: about 40secs!

```
Finished in 41.86 seconds (files took 0.44731 seconds to load)
```

Here's another spec that has JavaScript activated. Although it's much smaller (and only one full page load happens), I think the time it needs is improportionally less than the one above:

```
it 'allows to remove an existing finding', js: true, focus: true do
  visit edit_project_boilerplate_copy_path(@boilerplate_copy.project, @boilerplate_copy)

  click_link 'Remove finding'

  expect {
    click_button 'Update Boilerplate'
  } .to change { Finding.count }.by -1
end
```

It takes about 6-7secs:

```
Finished in 6.62 seconds (files took 0.52104 seconds to load)
```

So I wonder why the first one needs so much time. My full spec suite is around 400 specs and took around a minute, so by adding the new spec it increases to nearly 2 minutes! This isn't acceptable.

So: how can my JS spec be improved? Does it have to do with the many `visible: false` statements? Or the many `and change { ... }` stuff? Maybe both in interaction?

When removing all the lines that have a `visible: false` in them, it goes much faster:

```
Finished in 6.39 seconds (files took 0.41315 seconds to load)
```

I use capybara (2.5.0), rspec (3.3.0), rails (4.2.1), and poltergeist (1.7.0) with phantomjs (1.9.8) on OSX El Capitan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your test is so slow becauase you're running into Capybaras waiting behavior.  `#has_css?/have_css` will wait up to Capybara.default_max_wait_time seconds for matching elements to appear on the page before responding with false if they don't.  When you expect an element not to be on the page you want to be using #has_no_css?/have_no_css (or not_to #has_css?/have_css since they end up being the same thing) since that will return as soon as the element is not found.

```
has_css?(....)  #will wait until element appears or default_max_wait_time
has_no_css?(....)  #will wait until element is gone or default_max_wait_time
```

Basically in your case, you don't want to be using the `change` matcher with has_css? because it doesn't allow you to use the method that will match as soon as possible on each side of the action.  If you really want to keep the `change` matcher a potential option is to pass a small wait value to has_css? `wait: 0.5` or something which will decrease the max wait time for that item, but may need to be tweaked to allow for whatever actions occur on the page to actually complete

Comment: Thank you for your comment. It may be the case that I misunderstood the `visible: false` option? I'm checking for CSS selectors that definitely exist on the page, but aren't visible initially (`display: hidden`). When clicking on an element, the relevant elements are set to `display: block`. My intention is to make sure that the element first isn't visible, then after clicking the element becomes visible. Do I have false positives in my specs?

Comment: As documented - http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/capybara/Capybara%2FNode%2FFinders%3Aall - there are 5 acceptable values for the :visible option -- true, false, :all, :hidden, :visible  --   true == :visible, fallse == :all  -  so if you want to verify that an element is in the page but not visible you need to pass `visible: :hidden`  - false tells it to ignore visibility -  however - is it really important that it's in the page or just that it's not visible?  If you ever change to dynamically loading those elements your tests will break - think of feature tests from the users POV

Comment: Thank you. It's a pity that I can't stick to the `change { ... }` syntax with this, but I guess that's a minor inconvenience.